# SQL - nth order events of colors appearing first time tin lane1

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an event table with lane1 and lane2 mapping colors as below.

| event | lane1 | lane2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 79 | red | yellow |
| 83 | red | white |
| 87 | blue | red |
| 91 | yellow | white |
| 96 | green | white |
| 100 | navy | yellow |
| 103 | yellow | green |
| 107 | yellow | blue |
| 111 | yellow | navy |
| 115 | blue | navy |
| 119 | yellow | grey |
| 123 | white | grey |

Required Output:

Capture the nth entry of the color that appears in lane1 for the first time.
For the above input the required output is

| event | lane1 | nth_entry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 79 | red | 1 |
| 87 | blue | 1 |
| 91 | yellow | 2 |
| 96 | green | 1 |
| 100 | navy | 1 |
| 123 | white | 4 |

I tried aggregation query, like lane1, min(event) but not getting the required output.

```
select lane1, min(event) from colors group by lane1
```

Comment: postgres <> oracle, please update your post with only one DBMS tag

Comment: updated to postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One further option while exploiting window functions is:

- linearizing your data,
- computing the nth_entry
- extracting first value for each lane1 value

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT event_, lane1 AS lane, 1 AS numLane FROM tab
    UNION ALL
    SELECT event_, lane2 AS lane, 2 AS numLane FROM tab
), ranked AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY lane ORDER BY event_) AS nth_entry
    FROM cte
)
SELECT event_, lane, nth_entry
FROM ranked
WHERE numlane = 1
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY lane ORDER BY event_)
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/okiN6fN1GtTM6zYPfGqiyY/0).

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a self-`join` on the first occurrences of `lane1` values:

```
select e1.ev, e1.lane1, sum((e2.lane1 = e1.lane1 or e2.lane2 = e1.lane1)::int) 
from (select e.lane1, min(e.event) ev from events e group by e.lane1) e1 
join events e2 on e2.event <= e1.ev 
group by e1.ev, e1.lane1 order by e1.ev
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hW7o2tch).

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
WITH lane2_color_count as (
  SELECT
    lane2,
    COUNT(1) AS nth_entry

  FROM colors
  GROUP BY lane2
)

SELECT
  min(colors.event) as event,
  colors.lane1,
  lane2_color_count.nth_entry
FROM
 colors 
LEFT JOIN lane2_color_count
  ON lane2_color_count.lane2 = colors.lane1

GROUP BY colors.lane1, lane2_color_count.nth_entry

ORDER BY event
```

Comment: this is not giving right answer, pls cross check

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the `ORDER BY event` clause, I have edited the answer:
https://dbfiddle.uk/GKQwYN2U

Comment: Is your table called `colors`? (I assumed it was from your questions sample query)

Answer (score 1):

We unpivot `lane2` using `union all` and then use `row_number()` to give us the first time a color appears in `lane1` and how many time it appeared in `lane2` previously.

```
select    event
         ,color as lane1
         ,nth_entry
from 
         (
          select    *
                    ,row_number() over(partition by color, lane order by event) as rn
                    ,row_number() over(partition by color order by event)       as nth_entry
          from      (
                    select event, lane1 as color, 'lane1' as lane from t
          union all select event, lane2, 'lane2'                  from t
                    ) t
         ) t
where     lane = 'lane1'
and       rn = 1
order by  event
```

| event | lane1 | nth_entry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 79 | red | 1 |
| 87 | blue | 1 |
| 91 | yellow | 2 |
| 96 | green | 1 |
| 100 | navy | 1 |
| 123 | white | 4 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8sfwE_HK)